# Javascript prompt cancel terminates function

Tags: javascript, prompt

So I have a function that `prompt`s the user for a value (`element0`) and compares that value to one already existing (`elementIJ.name`). That part works OK, but here comes the problematic twist: I want the function to do something different when the `prompt` is cancelled (either by clicking Cancel or pressing the Esc key, for that matter), but instead it looks like the function is terminated. I've been running tests using `alert`, but the idea is to actually do other things. Here's my code:

```
var element0 = prompt('Enter element name').toUpperCase() ;
if ( element0 == null || element0 == '' || element0 == false || !element0 ) { alert('ALERT!') ; }
while ( element0 !== elementIJ.name.toUpperCase() )
  {
    element0 = prompt('Try again').toUpperCase() ;
    if ( element0 === null || element0 === '' || element0 === false ) { alert('ALERT!') ; }
  }
// ... do things for element0 === elementIJ.name.toUpperCase()
```

As I say, the bit without the `if` statements works OK, it's just the `prompt` cancelling that doesn't. I've been searching the web for answers, but it seems that most people have the exact opposite of my problem: that they want the cancelling to terminate the function... So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If you cancel the prompt, then `null` will be returned and `toUpperCase()` will fail, throwing an exception and effectively terminating the execution of your function.

Comment: You should always check the console for errors if something isn't working.

Comment: Thanks, Frédéric, that was exactly the problem :)
forgivenson, could you tell me how to do that? I started with this just some weeks ago and I'm now doing my tests using Brackets for the writing and Chrome for the actual testing.

Comment: On Chrome, CTRL+SHIFT+J. On IE, SHIFT+F12. On FireFox, CTRL+SHIFT-K
Of course, depends on OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do toUpperCase() at the first line because element0 might be cancelled. Try this:

## Edit Better Answer:

Here is a actually I believe what you were trying to do:
Replace 'TEST'

```
function promptTest(){
    var element0 = prompt('Enter element name');
    if ( element0 == null || element0 == '' || element0 == false || !element0 ) { 
        alert('cancelled!')
        return false; 
    }
    else{
        return element0.toUpperCase();
    }

}

var promptVar = promptTest();
while (promptVar && promptVar !== 'TEST' )
{
    promptVar = promptTest();
}
```

## Old Answer:

```
var element0 = prompt('Enter element name');
if ( element0 == null || element0 == '' || element0 == false || !element0 ) { 
    alert('ALERT!') ; 
}
else{
    element0 = element0.toUpperCase()
    console.log("element0: " + element0)
    while ( element0 !== elementIJ.name.toUpperCase() )
    {
        element0 = prompt('Try again').toUpperCase() ;
        if ( element0 === null || element0 === '' || element0 === false ) { alert('ALERT!') ; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(element0)` should be enough!